# Filter apply on element only if object is on the specific DIV, but not being inside of DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have script which detects two h4 elements and by position absolute it puts lines on them.

[how lines look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmZ0O.jpg)

if you scroll they start to fill with orange color. But since they are put as position absolute on entire body, the problem is when those elements are going into an DIV with background-color:orange because the lines that are filling are also orange and I would like to make them blue, by adding something like filter: Invert

[problem with orange line on orange background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljoPg.jpg)

So here is a question, if it's possible to make the line blue only if the lines are placed on that DIV with BG orange?
Maybe somehow it's possible to do it with JS viewport?

I will not add codes here of what I done because it's too long and too complicated.

But here is a short code of what I mean to help visualize the problem:

```html
<div style="height:400px; width:100%;">
</div>

<div style="height:400px; width:100%; background-color:orange;">
</div>

<div style="height:500px; width:100px; position: absolute; top:100px; left:50%; background-color:orange; border:solid grey 1px;">   
</div>
```

So the smaller orange div have border grey to help you see the whole orange div which is placed partialy on other div with background orange. So I want to achieve that the part of smaller orange block become different color for example blue if it's visible on that bigger orange div.
And ofcourse I cannot just put the smaller div inside of big one, because everything is placed with scripts that are complicated so I do not want to rewrite whole code. But if ofcourse if what I want to achieve is not possible then I will need to change whole block to different color and that's it.

Comment: Can you post a screen recording of the issue? How are lines made? Are they single entities or can be partially colored?

Comment: updated post with small code to help you visualize the problem and how the lines are placed.

Comment: Why change the div's colour on scroll? Just set it to a different colour from the start and problem solved, this way there isn't a distracting colour change of the bar. if that bar's colour should stay consistent throughout the experience

Comment: The problem is that you can't partially set the background color of an element. You would need to split your lines each time they overlap a different section, so you can set a different color for each one. It would all depend on your implementation, it will be difficult to help if you don't add your code and walk us through it.

Comment: The "easiest" thing I can think right now, if you want to make it dynamic, considering that sections can have variable sizes and that positions can be affected by responsiveness, is to track section colors on scroll and animatedly change the color of your whole lines accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLUTION!

Ahhh managed to do it with the trick of adding another DIV that detect position top of orange DIV and height of it, and places transaprent div on it with backdrop-filter.

[orange line changes to blue when entering orange div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdKh7.jpg)

The code without complicated JS that check top position of element.

```html
<div style="position:relative;">
  <div style="height:400px; width:100%;">
  </div>

  <div class="backdrop-reverse" style="height:400px; width:100%; background-color:orange;">
  </div>

  <div style="height:500px; width:100px; position: absolute; top:100px; left:50%; background-color:orange; border:solid grey 1px;">   
  </div>

  <!-- additional invisible block that changes color of everything on orange div -->
  <div style="backdrop-filter: hue-rotate(200deg); width:100%; height:400px; position: absolute; left:0; top:400px; content: ''; z-index:100; pointer-events: none;"></div>
  <style>
  .backdrop-reverse{
    overflow: hidden;
    filter: hue-rotate(160deg); /*Just a bit if luck with hue rotation, it creates very similar orange color, but it's not the same, might be problem with different hue rotations*/
  </style>
</div>
```